# How to parse XML with prefix in RobotFramework - #Robotframework

Tags: xml, automated-tests, robotframework

I Have the below XML

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NAMESPACE:RAIseQuery xmlns:NAMESPACE="urn:NAMESPACE:xsd:$RAIseQuery" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:NAMESPACE:xsd:$RAIseQuery RAIseQuery.xsd">
    <NAMESPACE:Sender>ABCDEF</NAMESPACE:Sender>
    <NAMESPACE:Received>PQRSTUV</NAMESPACE:Received>
    <NAMESPACE:Ref>ABC12345678</NAMESPACE:Ref>   
    <NAMESPACE:Waitforrevert xmlns="urn:xyz:std:xyz:2022:tech:xsd:abcd.123.001.01">
        <START1>
            <Id>PQRTSUV12345678910</Id>
        </START1>
        
    </NAMESPACE:Waitforrevert>
</NAMESPACE:RAIseQuery>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NAMESPACE:RAIseQuery xmlns:NAMESPACE="urn:NAMESPACE:xsd:$RAIseQuery" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:NAMESPACE:xsd:$RAIseQuery RAIseQuery.xsd">
    <NAMESPACE:Sender>ABCDEF</NAMESPACE:Sender>
    <NAMESPACE:Received>PQRSTUV</NAMESPACE:Received>
    <NAMESPACE:Ref>XYZ2345678</NAMESPACE:Ref>   
    <NAMESPACE:Waitforrevert xmlns="urn:xyz:std:xyz:2022:tech:xsd:abcd.123.001.01">
        <START1>
            <Id>DEFGSUV12345678910</Id>
        </START1>
        
    </NAMESPACE:Waitforrevert>
</NAMESPACE:RAIseQuery>
```

I am trying to edit the XML for my testcase and I used the below in Robotframework.

```
*** Settings ***
Library     XML use_lxml=yes

*** Test Cases ***
xml_with_namespace
    ${y}=   Parse   Xml ${IN_The_Path}
    Set Element Text    ${y}    XYZ2345678  xpath=.//NAMESPACE:Ref
    Set Element Text    ${y}    DEFGSUV12345678910xpath=.///NAMESPACE:Waitforrevert/START1/Id
    Save Xml    ${y}    ${Path2}
```

But I get below error. I dont know how to handle prefix and namespace in RBF and new to use this Library.

ERROR - SyntaxError: prefix 'NAMESPACE' not found in prefix map

Answer (score 0):

Try this Xpath:
`xpath:/NAMESPACE:RAIseQuery/NAMESPACE:Ref` and
`xpath:/NAMESPACE:RAIseQuery/NAMESPACE:Waitforrevert/START1/Id`